# from urllib.parse.quote change only the part after http://

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I want to quote an url. Here is a real-live example:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
start_url = "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jan Hackaert, Small Town (Town Gate at Gorkum?), NGA 53482.jpg"

quoted = quote(start_url)
```

The problem is that my `quoted`  url starts with "https%3A//" with "%3A" instead of ":".

QUESTION : How can I quote only the part after "https://" ?

I know that I can do something like this:

```
url_parts = start_url.split("://", 1)
url_parts[1] = quote(url_parts[1])
quoted = "://".join(url_parts)
```

But there are some caveats :

- what if the URL does not starts with "://" ?
- what if there is a "://" somewhere else in the url ? (filenames are often surprising)
- ... other stuff I didn't tough about.

QUESTION : is there something in urllib (or somewhere else) doing the work out of the box ?

EDIT: What if the url is already quoted ? ex: https://www.example.com/path%20with%20spaces

Comment: The approach is fine but you should use `url_parts[-1] = quote(url_parts[-1])` so that it quotes even if `://` isn't found

Comment: @Tranbi I'm able to deal with the caveats **I think of**. The point is to deal with the special cases I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of chatGPT, I come up with these functions:

```
def ensure_unquoted(url:str)->str:
    """Ensure that the url is not quoted."""
    if "%" in url:
        return urllib.parse.unquote(url)
    return url 


def quote_url(url: str) -> str:
    """Return a quoted version of the URL."""
    if url.startswith("http"):
        url_parts = url.split("://", 1)
        url_parts[1] = quote_url(url_parts[1])
        return "://".join(url_parts)

    # At this point the url does not contain "http://"
    unquoted = ensure_unquoted(url)
    return urllib.parse.quote(unquoted)
```

The two tricks are:

- a recursion to call `quote_url` on the part after `http://`
- first ensure that the url is not yet quoted (unquote if necessary), then quote to avoid double quoting.

I'm not sure this is optimal. Let me know if you have a better solution.